# how to block IP in django

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to add my IP address to the ignorable_404_urls in django settings.

My entry looks like this:

```
import re
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = (
    re.compile(r'^51\.20\.22\.14$'),


)
```

This doesn't not stop the 404 error emails from being generated.  This leads to me to believe my regular expression is wrong.

Is this the best way to stop the 404 emails?  If so is this the correct regular expression for an ip address?

Answer (score 0):

you can define your own middleware and block this ip there. This makes more sense, because once you want to block the ip, it should not come in into your urls.py, otherwise you have not blocked it. [here is how you can do it](http://www.django-tips.com/tip/django-how-to-block-ip-address-using-simple-middleware/23/)

you just need to override the `process_request` where you block the IP and return Forbidden HttpResponse

Comment: this is pretty cool, but it requires that I first add the url to the allowed_hosts in settings.